# gwt and javascript files

Tags: javascript, gwt

In my Google web toolkit application, my gwt.xml file includes the following line in the module:

```
<module rename-to='foo'>
...
  <script src="foo.js"></script>
...
```

My question is: where in my GWT project do I actually place foo.js so that it gets packed into the war when I compile my project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put it in a public folder. A public folder is a folder placed next to a client folder in the same package where your gwt.xml file is located. See also http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules

Comment: I have made a folder named `public` within the `src` directory. So, given my project name is `foo`, `com.google.sample.foo.client`,  `com.google.sample.foo.server`, `public` are all under the `src` folder. I have kept the `jquery.js` file and another `js` file `foo.js` inside the `public` folder. I have added the lines `<script src="jquery.js"  type='text/javascript'"></script>` and `<script src="blur.js"  type='text/javascript'"></script>` to the `gwt.xml` file.

Comment: Then I have added these lines in the `head` section of the `HTML` file in the `war` folder: `<script src="jquery.js"  type='text/javascript'"></script>` and `<script src="blur.js"  type='text/javascript'"></script>`. The `blur.js` contains a single `click` handler for an element already defined in the `HTML` file. However, when I click on that element in the browser page, nothing happens. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Did you put the scripts in `com.google.sample.foo.public` or the `public` directory under the `src` directory? Because it should be next to the `client` directory? Also when adding it as script to the HTML page you would need to add the module name to the path, because the files in public are placed in the modulename subfolder. i.e.: `<script src=foo/jquery.js>`. Or insert them via the script tag in your module gwt.xml file: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion (without the module name in the src path).

Comment: I made a new folder named `public`, at the same level as `war`, `src`, `test`. I have kept both files there. I didn't understand your `module` part, please explain a bit more. What do I now need to do in the XML and HTML files to make these scripts working?

Comment: The public folder must be placed in the directory where your `<module>.gwt.xml` is, otherwise GWT can't find it. It must be at the same level as the `client` directory. If you have this correct, you will find in the war a directory with your modulename. This directory has all GWT generated files. Anything in a public directory will also be in that directory. To access them from your HTML page, set the src path to this folder, hence the module reference. If you put the script tags in your gwt.xml file,GWT will take care of the path and you can specify the src tag in the gwt.xml as you have now.

Comment: Well, the `xml` file is in the `com.google.gwt.sample.foo` folder, which itself is located in the `src` folder, the `src` folder being directly under the root folder `foo`. The `com.google.gwt.sample.foo` and `com.google.gwt.sample.foo.client` are at the same level (both under `foo`), so how can the `public` folder be where the `xml` file is and also at the same level as `client` directory?

Comment: If you want, I can send a screenshot of the directory structure. But I don't know where to upload it, given it's not my question...

Comment: The `public` directory should be in `com.google.gwt.sample.foo` : `com.google.gwt.sample.foo.public`.

Comment: Okay, but when I am trying to create a package named `public` in the `com.google.gwt.sample.foo` (which now contains only the `xml` file), Eclipse is not allowing me to do so, stating that ** Invalid package name. 'public' is not a valid Java identifier**.

Comment: You should create it as `new Folder` instead of as package

Comment: There's no option like `Folder`.

Comment: Right click on the directory were you want to add the directory and Select: `New` -> `General` -> `Folder`

Comment: Yeah yeah, done that. Now should I place both my `blur.js` and `jquery.js` files in that folder?

Comment: You said something like **Also when adding it as script to the HTML page you would need to add the module name to the path, because the files in public are placed in the modulename subfolder. i.e.: <script src=foo/jquery.js>** What does that mean? And as for the `xml` file, if I add the lines `<script src="blur.js"></script>` and `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`, will that do? Or do I need to anything else in the `xml` file?

Comment: Files in the public directory are placed in the war in the subdirectory where the GWT compiler files generates the js and resource files. If you add the scripts tag in the HTML page the src path to the script must be relative to your HTML page. If the directory name of the generated files is `foo` the src path should be as explained: `foo/jquery.js`. If you add them to the xml the notation you mention should work, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion

Comment: So after I have placed the two files `blur.js` and `jquery.js` file in the `public` folder like you told, I need to reference them in the `HTML` file like `<script src = 'foo/jquery.js></script>`, right?

Comment: yes, just like you refer to any resource in a HTML page; relative to the HTML page itself.

Comment: And what modifications do I need to make to the `xml` file?

Comment: Or place the script tags in your HTML page or place them in you xml file. If you place them in your HTML page, you don't have to change anything to your xml file.

Comment: Oh, it's almost working fine now. Except one thing, when I added the `blur.js` (along with the `jquery.js` file), it contained 2 lines. After adding theses files, I changed the `blur.js` file. But the change is not reflecting even after I restart the whole app. The source code in the browser is still showing the old 2 lines of code from `blur.js`. How do i keep the changes updated?

Comment: Hi Hilbrand, please answer my question mate! Last one, plus that even though the `blur.js` code contains a simple `$(function() { alert("Cool"); });`, the GWT page doesn't throw a pop-up on page-load, even though the source code of the `blur.js` file appears just as it is.

Comment: Is the blur.js updated in the war directory? If so it might be the caching of the browser, and you need to hard refresh. For the second question. Does it even work when you leave out the gwt part in the HTML page?

Comment: What do you mean by leave out the `gwt` part? The HTML page has only an empty wrapper `div`, which is used in GWT as `RootPanel.get("#bodywrapper").add(...)`...And I have placed the `blur.js` file in the `public` directory as you mentioned. There is no such file in the `war` directory, not even under the `foo` subdirectory under `war`, which contains the `foo.nocache.js` file...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23360/discussion-between-hilbrand-bouwkamp-and-cupidvogel)