# GWT including external javascript file from module's manifest

Tags: javascript, gwt, manifest

So I read the documentation about including an external Javascript file directly in the module manifest yourApplication.gwt.xml (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html)

I have this javascript file called iscroll.js and stored in the war/ folder of the GWT project.

I added the line to the module's manifest of my GWT application:

```
<script src="iscroll.js"/>
```

Then from the `onModuleLoad()` method I call this native JSNI method:

```
private native void initJavascript() /*-{
  $wnd.myScroll = new iScroll('jokeWrapperLabel');
}-*/;
```

Then when I run the code in the browser I keep getting "iScroll is undefined".

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

This is the output of the "iScroll is undefined error"

```
18:32:41.780 [ERROR] [jollyjokesprogwt] Unable to load module entry point class com.wanderlust.jollyjokespro.gwt.client.JollyJokesProGWT (see associated exception for details)
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): iScroll is not defined
 stack: ReferenceError: iScroll is not defined
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (unknown source)
    at __gwt_jsInvoke (http://127.0.0.1:8888/jollyjokesprogwt/hosted.html?jollyjokesprogwt:76:35)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/jollyjokesprogwt/hosted.html?jollyjokesprogwt:280:16
    at C (http://127.0.0.1:8888/jollyjokesprogwt/jollyjokesprogwt.nocache.js:2:148)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8888/jollyjokesprogwt/jollyjokesprogwt.nocache.js:8:593
 type: not_defined
 arguments: iScroll
 __gwt_ObjectId: 91
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.wanderlust.jollyjokespro.gwt.client.JollyJokesProGWT.initJavascript(JollyJokesProGWT.java)
    at com.wanderlust.jollyjokespro.gwt.client.JollyJokesProGWT.onModuleLoad(JollyJokesProGWT.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you inspect the page after your module loads (using Firebug or Chrome dev tools) do you see a `<script>` tag on the page with `src="iscroll.js"` ?

Comment: Jason thanks for answer!
So I tried Chrome dev tools but I can't figure it out anything from the generated jascript code. Which file exactly should I debug to find this information? Could you give some instruction on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to place the JavaScript file in a public folder, see this stackoverflow answer on how that works: [gwt and javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659433/gwt-and-javascript-files)
and the call to `iScroll(..` must be `$wnd.iScroll(..`.