# Google +1 for GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I'm having problems to include the Google +1 widget to my GWT webapp. In detail, the app seems not to find the included script:

```
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" />
```

which I included in the applications `gwt.xml` file. To the site itself I added an `InlineHTML` object like follows:

```
verticalPanel.add( new InlineHTML("<g:plusone></g:plusone>" ) );
```

The +1 widget is not shown on the final page, nor any error message. Any hints?

Comment: Can you see both the script tag and g:plusone tag in the page source in the browser developer tools?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It may find it useful:

[gwt-and-javascript-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659433/gwt-and-javascript-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser issue. It works on Chrome or Firefox, not on Safari.

Comment: Do you know if this has been fixed yet?