# How to import javascript files / library into GWT (Eclipse)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gwt, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gwt and javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659433/gwt-and-javascript-files)

Seems like a simple enough task, but i'm having trouble doing it at the moment...

edit: actual import, not reference through script tags in manifest files...

Comment: can you describe what do you mean by "actual import"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to add import of js to your html file below import of gwt nocached javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mygwt.nocache.js"></script>
<script src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
```